# Combining GLX (OpenGL) and X11 graphics

Tags: opengl, user-interface, x11

I have to write an application on Linux using X11 for the interface (in C++). The application uses GLX to render some openGL graphics, but I also need to write some custom UI for this app within the same window.

When I create window I created a GC and a GLX context. Ideally I'd need to "draw" the openGL into a region of the window (say the left part) and the draw the UI on the side of the GL viewport.

How can I do that?

- how can i combine GLX and GC drawing calls, such as XDrawString for example.
- what would be the best way for me to create a layout within the same window, reserving a region of the window in which I draw the GL content, and having another region of the window in which I draw the UI using X calls. Do I need to create sub-windows for that?

Comment: Did you consider using a toolkit combining X11 & OpenGL?

Comment: Consider [libsdl](http://www.libsdl.org/), [QtOpenGL](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtopengl-index.html) etc...

Comment: yes, I did, I can not use Qt for this project, or any other library. Using X11 and GLX is my only solution.

Comment: Are you ready to spend many months or years of effort? At least, study the source code such free software libraries, it will teach you a lot! And there is also [GtkGLExt](https://projects.gnome.org/gtkglext/), or [FOX](http://www.fox-toolkit.org/) etc...

Comment: Thank you but this is not answering the question. I know about Qt, I am just asking if someone can point me into ways of doing this, and yes, I am looking at the source code of Qt.

Comment: I was commenting, not answering!

Answer (score 1):

I actually found a useful answer here:

[Create GLX context in specific region of a window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280963/create-glx-context-in-specific-region-of-a-window)

The idea is to spawn a sub-window from the current window and draw the GL content to it.

Comment: That would be the standard way of doing things in the GLX world.

Comment: Thank you. I am looking at the code in Qt, it's of course hard when you are not familiar with it to understand how things work, but it doesn't seem to make any call to X function for drawing things... does it mean then that it does all drawing in GL for Widgets?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to use [BindTexImage](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/texture_from_pixmap.txt) extension, draw your X11 (via core / xrender / whatever ) commands to offscreen pixmap and then later composite it as a texture.

Comment: You can do the same but other way: do all your GL rendering to offscreen pixmap ( you can associate gl context with any drawable, not just window ) and then use XCopyArea or XRenderComposite to copy your gl scene to a window

Comment: Great to you know some code around that I could use as an example. No worries otherwise I will figure it out, but it will speed up the process.